# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question and there is no reason it needs to be open since it is not soliciting answers.

Comment: While the reasons to close this question are good, “2021 Community Moderator Election [closed]” is really problematic. The “danger” of a pointless answer here is much less than anyone getting the impression the election is over (particularly on mobile, where the sidebar announcing the election is instead a footer). Thus I am voting to reopen this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the election has ended.

Comment: I've reopened the question, mostly because it looks weird to have a post announcing the election be closed as off-topic. I don't think it really causes any harm to leave it open, and there's no benefit to closing it - anyone visiting the linked elections page will see that the latest election ended with nitsua60 and Oblivious Sage being elected.

Comment: @V2Blast what sort of answer might one post to this question?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Not every meta-post needs to strictly conform to the Q/A format that mainsite does. Sometimes we just need a way to make announcements and a meta-post is the best format we currently have to do that.